# get_option / wp_localize_script Not Working in OOP Plug In

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, options, oop

Got this working the other day in a single-file php plugin which only consisted of functions.

Now I am trying it out with the [WordPress Plugin Boilerplate](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/tree/master/plugin-name) which is an OOP approach with a lot of different classes.

In short, I am looking at two different classes/files

`includes/class-ebay-keyword-suggest.php` and `admin/class-ebay-keyword-suggest-admin.php`

The first being the core plugin class, and the latter being the admin-specific functionality.

First, `class-ebay-keyword-suggest.php` `__construct()`'s

```
public function __construct() {
    if ( defined( 'EBAY_KEYWORD_SUGGEST_VERSION' ) ) {
        $this->version = EBAY_KEYWORD_SUGGEST_VERSION;
    } else {
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
    }
    $this->plugin_name = 'ebay-keyword-suggest';

    $this->load_dependencies();
    $this->set_locale();
    $this->define_admin_hooks();
    $this->define_public_hooks();
    $this->register_admin_menu();
}
```

`load_dependencies` loads the `class-ebay-keyword-suggest-admin.php` file, among others.

ends with defining `$this->loader` as such:

`$this->loader = new Ebay_Keyword_Suggest_Loader();`

`define_admin_hooks` loads up my scripts and stylesheets

```
private function define_admin_hooks() {
    $plugin_admin = new Ebay_Keyword_Suggest_Admin( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );
    $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_styles' );
    $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_scripts' );
}
```

Proceeded by `register_admin_menu`:

```
private function register_admin_menu() {
    $plugin_admin = new Ebay_Keyword_Suggest_Admin( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );
    add_action( 'admin_init', array( $plugin_admin, 'ebay_keyword_suggest_settings_init' ) );
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $plugin_admin, 'ebay_keyword_suggest_add_admin_menu' ) );
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_localize' ) );
}
```

`ebay_keyword_suggest_settings_init` is where I am registering the option/setting `ebay_keyword_suggest_settings` with callbacks

```
public function ebay_keyword_suggest_settings_init() { 

register_setting( 'pluginPage', 'pluginPage', array($this, 'ebay_keyword_suggest_settings'));

add_settings_section(
    'ebay_keyword_suggest_pluginPage_section', 
    __( 'Your section description', '' ),
    array($this, 'ebay_keyword_suggest_settings_section_callback'),
    'pluginPage'
);

add_settings_field( 
    'ebay_keyword_suggest_checkbox_field_0', 
    __( 'Settings field description', '' ), 
    array($this, 'ebay_keyword_suggest_checkbox_field_0_render'),
    'pluginPage', 
    'ebay_keyword_suggest_pluginPage_section' 
);
}
```

Next in line in the `add_action` functions of `register_admin_menu` via `ebay_keyword_suggest_add_admin_menu`

```
public function ebay_keyword_suggest_add_admin_menu() {
    add_options_page( 'eBay Keyword Suggest', 'eBay Keyword Suggest', 'manage_options', 'ebay_keyword_suggest',  array($this, 'ebay_keyword_suggest_options_page') );
}
```

Then we get to this line:

`add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_localize' ) );`

```
public function enqueue_localize( $hook ) {
    $getoption = get_option( 'ebay_keyword_suggest_settings' );
    $enabled = $getoption['ebay_keyword_suggest_checkbox_field_0'];
    wp_localize_script( $this->plugin_name, 'ekw_script_vars', array( 'enabled' => __($enabled) ) );
}
```

As you can see the first instance of `get_option` is initiated here under the variable `$getoption`... doing a `var_dump` always returns `false` (and of course `wp_localize_script` does not work properly as it is not getting the proper option variable.

Getting this working in a single php file was very easy with a combination of `add_action`'s above the functions and a simple initiation of `register_setting( 'pluginPage', 'title_char_count_settings' );` followed by retrieving the setting with just simple `get_option( 'title_char_count_settings' );`

This OOP approach is a lot more tricky... I have to be *close* I'm thinking.. where is the hiccup in this?

Comment: You used `register_setting( 'pluginPage', 'pluginPage'` - is that second `pluginPage` intended?

Comment: Yeah... it's just `option_group` and `option_name` they can be the same.  Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/

Comment: Yes, but it's the name of the *database* option, which you should use with `get_option()`. Like with the second parameter in `register_setting( 'pluginPage', 'title_char_count_settings' )` ..

Comment: Yes, wow, that's exactly right! Completely overlooked on my part. Changed as noted and now it works. Thank you. If you want to add an answer I can accept it so this can be closed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *second* parameter for [`register_setting()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/) is the *database* option name which you would use with `get_option()` just as you've done successfully with the `title_char_count_settings` option: `register_setting( 'pluginPage', 'title_char_count_settings' )` and `get_option( 'title_char_count_settings' );`.

So I'm guessing that you either:

1. Made a typo in the `register_setting()` call in your `ebay_keyword_suggest_settings_init()` function:

   ```php
   // You used this:
   register_setting( 'pluginPage', 'pluginPage', array($this, 'ebay_keyword_suggest_settings'));

   // But perhaps you meant this? (Note the option name - the second parameter)
   register_setting( 'pluginPage', 'ebay_keyword_suggest_settings', array($this, 'ebay_keyword_suggest_settings'));
   ```
2. Or you made a typo in your `get_option()` call in your `enqueue_localize()` function, where you should have used `get_option( 'pluginPage' )`. But it's unlikely that you would use `pluginPage` as the name for that option? :)